# multipartRequest to send multiple images to server using volley ,but it is taking more time to upload images

Tags: android, android-volley, multipartform-data, image-uploading

I am taking photos from camera and keeping in a list of upto 5 images .To send these imagelist, I am using the `volley multipartRequest` but it is taking a lot of time to upload the images to server . I even tried compressing the images into byte string format before storing in the list

Any solution?

Comment: I faced this issue too. That's why I use `jobIntentService` to let it run on background.

Comment: use AndroidFastNetworking library.

Comment: John Joe can u please send me the code @ gsandeep3082@gmail.com  Thank u

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya i will look into that thanks